Inbuilt microphone not detected on Thinkpad E14 Gen 6 (Pop OS)
I've just installed Pop OS as a dual boot on a new Thinkpad E14 Gen 6, running an AMD Ryzen 5 7535 CPU.
I've got a problem though: the inbuilt laptop microphone is not being detected in the sound settings! The "Input" dropdown is greyed out, with no options to select anything. The laptop speakers work fine.
One of the first things I tried was installing pavucontrol. This told me that the microphone was "unplugged".
Running arecord --list-devices gave me the output
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: CX8070 Analog [CX8070 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Which I think implies that some part of Linux is detecting the microphone?
Based off of my erratic googling, I've also tried blacklisting snd_soc_skl to no effect, and briefly tried blacklisting snd_hda_intel - which just made my speakers stop working. I reversed that!
On top of this, I've ran this series of modprobe commands, to no visible effect:
  131  sudo modprobe snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
  132  sudo modprobe snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
  133  sudo modprobe snd_soc_dmic

On the Windows boot, the microphone is detected and works fine! Some answers I've seen online have been telling me it's a kernel issue, but many of the answers are telling people to upgrade to 6.5 or 6.6. I'm currently on 6.9.3-76060903-generic.
I'm not really sure what to do! Any help would be appreciated - or something to help me know where to look.
******* DIAGNOSTIC ZONE *********

Here's the result of a journalctl, grepped to only include sound stuff - journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"
Jul 29 10:07:20 pop-os kernel: ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP17.HDAU.PWRS: New power resource
Jul 29 10:07:20 pop-os kernel: [drm] DP-HDMI FRL PCON supported
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_pci_acp6x 0000:05:00.5: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: CX8070: BIOS auto-probing.
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for CX8070: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x16/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:05:00.1: bound 0000:05:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card0/input20
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card0/input21
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1/input23
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card0/input22
Jul 29 10:07:21 pop-os kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1/input24

Here's the output of pactl's list of sources - pactl list sources
Source #49
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analogue Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "CX8070 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        alsa.name = "CX8070 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:1"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "47"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "2"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "CX8070 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "48"
        object.serial = "49"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "10384503"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "1"
    Ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
    Active Port: analog-output-speaker
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #50
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo
    Description: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Analogue Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "CX8070 Analog"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        alsa.name = "CX8070 Analog"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "front:1"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "47"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "CX8070 Analog"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:front:1:capture"
        priority.driver = "2009"
        priority.session = "2009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "49"
        object.serial = "50"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "10384503"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.string = "1"
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm

Finally, here's the pactl information on sound cards - pactl list cards
Card #47
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.1
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c8000 irq 84"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.1"
        device.description = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.1"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "10380399"
        device.product.id = "0x1640"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "35"
        object.id = "46"
        object.serial = "47"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c8000 irq 84"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "0"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 3, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: off
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "hdmi"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2

Card #48
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6
    Driver: alsa
    Owner Module: n/a
    Properties:
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:05:00.6"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_05_00.6"
        device.nick = "HD-Audio Generic"
        device.plugged.usec = "10384503"
        device.product.id = "0x15e3"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.6/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        media.class = "Audio/Device"
        factory.id = "14"
        client.id = "35"
        object.id = "47"
        object.serial = "48"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0x806c0000 irq 85"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.string = "1"
    Profiles:
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "mic"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                card.profile.port = "0"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                port.type = "speaker"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                card.profile.port = "1"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
            Properties:
                port.type = "headphones"
                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                card.profile.port = "2"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo

If any more information is needed I'll update this post with those later!

I know it's Pop OS, but I had the same problem on Debian, and the solution was to upgrade the kernel to v6.10.10 using these commands:
cd /tmp

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.10.10/amd64/linux-headers-6.10.10-061010_6.10.10-061010.202409121037_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.10.10/amd64/linux-headers-6.10.10-061010-generic_6.10.10-061010.202409121037_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.10.10/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-6.10.10-061010-generic_6.10.10-061010.202409121037_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.10.10/amd64/linux-modules-6.10.10-061010-generic_6.10.10-061010.202409121037_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo reboot

